# Replacement window - stucco on face of trim?

Tags: replacement, stucco

I had replacement windows installed several years ago and plan to "clean up" around them before painting the house. I would like to know if it's safe to stucco on the face of the green highlighted areas for the window shown in the attached image. I plan to adhere a vinyl stucco casing bead to the highlighted areas and apply stucco on it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly could stucco as you wrote. I would suspect that matching the texture would be difficult if not impossible.  More troubling would be the inevitable cracks that will come from the new stucco not binding well with the old stucco.

You could grind the paint off all the edges of the old stucco. Apply a binding agent and then try to continue the texture over to cover the edges you highlighted.  that would be a lot of work for what I would consider a very small reward.

I would just clean all of the window frame and paint the stucco that is already there.  But it is not my house and I'm not doing all that work.